# What elements of $G$ are in the equivalence class containg $a$, for an equivalence relation $\sim$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, equivalence-relations

[image]

For question (b),
it seems to me that there are only two elements in the equivalence class of $a$ in $G$,
which is $a$ and $a^{-1}$. Am I wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: Welcome to math.se. Posting images with problems is often discouraged. You can learn how to typeset math on this site at [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: How does the order of $a$ impact your answer to (b)? What if $a$ has order $2$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  If $|a|\gt2$, then $|\bar a|=2$. Otherwise, it's $|\bar a|=1$.